# Magento 2 REST API - Override Item Price while adding to Cart

Tags: magento2, price, overrides, sales-order, rest-api

I am trying to create orders via **REST API** with the steps listed in the following link.

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/order-tutorial/order-intro.html

I want to change the **price** of the item when adding to the cart. But the price is not getting overridden and it always takes the **default Product price**.

Any possible help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me to do this i put all prices manually in the Json and it is working for me, Please see this JSON

```
{
  "entity": {
    "state": "new",
    "status": "pending",
    "base_discount_amount": "15.870000",
    "base_grand_total": 849.7,
    "base_shipping_amount": 10,
    "base_shipping_incl_tax": 10,
    "base_subtotal": 793.35,
    "base_subtotal_incl_tax": 855.55,
    "base_tax_amount": 62.2,
    "customer_email": "yourmail@mail.com",
    "customer_id": "1",
    "customer_is_guest": 0,
    "discount_amount": "15.870000",
    "ext_customer_id": 0,
    "grand_total": 849.7,
    "shipping_amount": "10.000000",
    "shipping_description": "Shipping Method",
    "shipping_incl_tax": 10,
    "store_id": 1,
    "subtotal": 793.35,
    "subtotal_incl_tax": 855.55,
    "tax_amount": 62.2,
    "total_item_count": 2,
    "total_qty_ordered": 6,
    "items": [
      {
        "discount_percent": "2.000000",
        "name": "ProductName1",
        "original_price": "135.300000",
        "price": "135.300000",
        "price_incl_tax": "146.120000",
        "product_id": "45",
        "qty_ordered": "5.000000",
        "row_total": "676.500000",
        "sku": "A00005",
        "store_id": 1,
        "tax_amount": "53.040000",
        "tax_percent": "8.000000",
        "product_option": {}
      },
      {
        "discount_percent": "2.000000",
        "name": "ProductName2",
        "original_price": "116.850000",
        "price": "116.850000",
        "price_incl_tax": "126.200000",
        "product_id": "26",
        "qty_ordered": "1.000000",
        "row_total": "116.850000",
        "sku": "A00005",
        "store_id": 1,
        "tax_amount": "9.160000",
        "tax_percent": "8.000000",
        "product_option": {}
      }
    ],
    "billing_address": {
      "city": "city",
      "country_id": "",
      "customer_id": 1,
      "email": "yourmail@mail.com",
      "firstname": "firstname",
      "lastname": "lastname",
      "postcode": "33332",
      "region": "",
      "region_id": "28",
      "street": [
        "Address"
      ],
      "telephone": "123456"
    },
    "payment": {
      "amount_ordered": 0,
      "base_amount_ordered": 0,
      "base_shipping_amount": 0,
      "entity_id": 0,
      "method": "checkmo",
      "shipping_amount": 0
    },
    "extension_attributes": {
      "shipping_assignments": [
        {
          "shipping": {
            "address": {
              "city": "city",
              "country_id": "US",
              "customer_id": 1,
              "firstname": "firstname",
              "lastname": "lastname",
              "postcode": "33332",
              "region": "",
              "region_id": "28",
              "street": [
                "Address"
              ],
              "telephone": "123456"
            },
            "method": "flatrate_flatrate",
            "total": {
              "base_shipping_amount": 0,
              "base_shipping_incl_tax": 0,
              "shipping_incl_tax": 0
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

don't forget to change the

- customer_id
- email
- Product name
- Product SKU
  -Product ID

  it is very important

Comment: This request JSON is for the endpoint
http://{hostname}/rest/default/V1/orders - POST.

This works good for me too. But inventory for the items is not getting reduced. Did you face this issue? If so, please suggest the solution.